# How to mark edges on flat plane after shade smooth/auto smooth?

Tags: game-engine, edges

I'm creating a barrel for a game. I was able to mark the seems on the side as sharp (Since there is an angle associated with it) giving the illusion of planks without adding additional vertices. I was hoping to do something similar to the edges on the top to also give the illusion of planks. Mark sharp doesn't do anything, and I haven't found a way to show the edges without adding additional vertices.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way around this geometry wise, however you might use a custom normal map via image texture. That is perfect for this type of situation, and is often used in game assets for that reason.

Comment: Thanks for the response! That's unfortunate to hear. I'm using a palette to color these, so I'm not really looking to add any image textures. I'll just go with the additional vertices. Thanks!